# Invalid ELF header error after solving invalid syntax async error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am currently using TensorFlow 1.9.0 to set up an object recognition camera. While doing so I have run into a few issues.

Firstly, I got the error:

```
File "/home/crop14/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 151
    return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TFE_ContextSetAsyncForThread(arg1, async)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I solved this error by following this article, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690

and replacing the async arguments with async1 however, once I completed this fix I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crop14/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/crop14/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1108, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: ./_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header
```

I have done a fair amount of research however considering I am fairly new to this side of programming, I was not successful. Any support regarding this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow?  This kind of error usually means that you installed the wrong architecture, like installing x64 binaries on an M1 chip or vice versa.

Comment: I am currently using a raspberry pi 4b to setup this camera. I also used this tutorial to install TensorFlow: https://linuxhint.com/install-tensorflow-raspberry-pi/

Comment: So you didn't, for example, copy a virtual environment from a different architecture?

Comment: I am not sure, would there be a specific command that I would've used that could have installed it? I am following this tutorial to set this object detection camera up, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npZ-8Nj1YwY

Comment: Many of the architectures that are used in this video are outdated so I had to find alternatives